# I need change class for CSS of asp:Panel with VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have problems with changing class of CSS in my asp:Panel. I try a lot of tips here but anyone help me. Code of my ItemTemplate is:

```html
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Panel class="item" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="CustomerNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CustomerName") %>' />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="LastIncomeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastIncome") %>' />
        <br />
     </asp:Panel>
</ItemTemplate>
```

and i try something like this:

```js
Protected Sub MyEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim dt As New Date
        Dim dv As System.Data.DataView
        Dim thePanel As HtmlGenericControl = New HtmlGenericControl("item")

        dv = CType(SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty), DataView)
        Dim s As String
        s = dv.Table.Rows.Item(0).Item(1)
        LastIncome = Convert.ToDateTime(s)

        If LastIncome.AddHours(1) < Now Then
            thePanel.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color:red") 'Problem
        Else
            thePanel.Attributes("class") = "itemGreen" 'Ok
        End If
End Sub
```

I have tried this `thePanel.Attributes.Add` or `thePanel.Attributes("class") = "itemGreen"` but it do not function on `OnLoad="MyEvent"` in my ListView declaration.

Can you help me? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set it with a function with an eval.

```
<asp:Panel CssClass='<%# GetCssClass(Eval("LastIncome")) %>' runat="server">
```

That way you don't need to handle any event or try to figure out which element/item to use.

The function would look like this and do any logic needed to return the right css.

```
Function GetCssClass(ByVal lastIncome As DateTime) As String
```

I would also suggest to have a class called itemRed instead of setting the color red directly in the style attribute.

If you really want to use an event, I would suggest you use an other one than load. Check the [ItemCreated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemcreated(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can use thePanel.CssClass = "myCssClass".
Also, use Panel insteal of HtmlGenericControl.

Comment: It write me that `CssClass is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.HtmlGenericControl`.

Comment: For CssClass to work `Dim thePanel As HtmlGenericControl = New HtmlGenericControl("item")`
 should not be a HtmlGenericControl, use a Panel instead.